# MongoDB installation size is huge

Tags: arch-linux, mongodb, aur, rolling-release

I need *MongoDB* to install on Arch Linux. It needs 180+GB free space for installation.
However, I have 99GB partition where Arch Linux is installed and 107GB partition free.
Can I installed MongoDB by ignoring all? Please suggest me how to get MongoDB

Answer (score 5):

You're likely building the [`mongodb`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mongodb/) package from AUR, which requires creating a source checkout and storing all the build artefacts, so yes, it tends to get rather big.

Instead, you might consider using the [`mongodb-bin`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mongodb-bin/) package, which uses the prebuilt binaries from the MongoDB repository for Ubuntu. In total, that should require on the order of a few hundred megabytes instead of several gigabytes.

Comment: sir, how can I check to download size of AUR file before download it

Comment: You can't, since they are downloaded on demand and may generate artefacts as they are built or packaged. You can only infer it by reading the PKGBUILD, sources, and documentation.

Comment: After installation mongodb-bin only, I am not able to start it 
I  give the command **mongo** and it gives the error message
""""MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-04-02T17:12:19.801-0400 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17""""

Comment: Sorry, but MongoDB-specific debugging questions are not on-topic here -- please feel free to ask them in a MongoDB-specific forum. :-)

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the help